# STL Map throwing an error upon search attempt

Tags: c++, string, stl, maps

I am trying to create a map full of strings as keys and integers as values.  The problem begins when I try and search with it.  Can someone tell me where I went wrong?  Is it that I have two Maps in the same statement?

```
    invale is "ale"
    roomno = 2;
    // roomlist is a map
    // rinventory is another map

    if( roomlist[roomno].rinventory.find( invale ) != map<string, int>::end());
```

The error I get follows.  What overloaded function?  It really is a lengthy error.

```
error C2668: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::end' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree(569): could be 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::end(void) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree(564): or       'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator std::_Tree<_Traits>::end(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,int,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,int>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(void)'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
if( roomlist[roomno].rinventory.find( invale ) != roomlist[roomno].rinventory.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if( roomlist[roomno].rinventory.find( invale ) != roomlist[roomno].rinventory.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

`map::end()` method is not static.

The proper way is like this :

```
map<string, int>::iterator it = roomlist[roomno].rinventory.find( invale );
if( it != roomlist[roomno].rinventory.end())
  // do stuff
```